# Sagemaker ML - Load Tensorflow model endpoint directly inside a lambda function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I've already managed to create a lambda function that loads a model.pb from S3 and apply object detection to an input image (installed tensorflow 1.12)

Is it possible to load a Sagemaker model/endpoint-configuration inside a lambda function ? I mean install all packages needed inside the lambda, without deploying an endpoint/ec2-like instance.

I guess inference performance would drop, but the solution seems to be more cost effective and scalable ready.

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker Endpoints only run on EC2 instances which are configured as part of the EndpointConfig. You can't use SageMaker models and deploy them onto Lambda.